# Jquery & PHP to show tables in a loop

Tags: php, html, jquery

i'm using Jquery and PHP to show Questions & Answers in a tables .. i'm using FOREACH LOOP to print the results, but i don't know how to show only one question in the click, this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('$#answer').click(function(){  

    $('#result').fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);



    });
    });
</script>
{foreach $essay as $question}
<div style="float: right;width:72%;margin-right:20px;">
<div class="menuhead">
{$ci->lang->line('question')}
</div>
          <div class="box"> 
          <button id="answer-{$question.id}" >ANSWER</button>
        <p style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">{$question.question}</p>   
        <p style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;"><span style="color:#001cac;font-weight:bold;">{$ci->lang->line('answers')}:</span> {$ci->essay->answers_count($question.id)}</p>    
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="result-{$question.id}" style="display:none;">{$question.id}</div>
        {/foreach}
```

another code "doesn't work also :( "

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.answer').click(function(){
        var i = $('.answer').index(this);  
        $('.result').eq(i).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
    });
});
</script>
{foreach $essay as $question}
<div style="float: right;width:72%;margin-right:20px;">
<div class="menuhead">
{$ci->lang->line('question')}
</div>
          <div class="box"> 
         <button id="answer-{$question.id}" class="answer">ANSWER</button>
        <p style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">{$question.question}</p>   
        <p style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;"><span style="color:#001cac;font-weight:bold;">{$ci->lang->line('answers')}:</span> {$ci->essay->answers_count($question.id)}</p>    
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="result-{$question.id}" class="result" style="display:none;">{$question.id}</div>
        {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click, you can hide all divs with the name "box" and show only the div that you clicked.

Comment: That's Ok .. but how can i make it to show only the div i clicked ? i have to put all of their ids in the Jquery or what ?!

Comment: When you click in class answer, find the parent class with name "box". $(this).closest(".box").show();
Where this, is the element that you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

So if I am to understand correctly, you problem is that, when you click an `answer` button all `result` div's are showing.

You have potentially two problems here.

First, I am not certain how any of your jQuery is working right now, as you use classes like `answer-#` and `result-#` where `#` would represent some id value.  If you need unique id for these elements' generate the id's into id property of the element, not the class.  Your element should probably look something like:

```
<button id="answer-{$question.id}" class="answer">ANSWER</button>
```

Second, you make no attempt in your jQuery to relate the button clicked with the appropriate target division to show.  You should use `$(this)` to determine the actual clicked element and work from there accordingly.

This is made a little difficult due to lack of common parent element in DOM. So without seeing the full HTML and knowing how to most concretely relate them, I would suggest using an approach to determine the index of the clicked answer button and show the result div at the same index value.  Of course this assumes there is a one-to-one correlation between the index value of elements in these collections and that the index value for the answer matches the index value for the result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.answer').click(function(){
        var i = $('.answer').index(this);  
        $('.result').eq(i).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok i've changed my classes to ids :  <button id="answer-{$question.id}" >ANSWER</button> and <div id="result-{$question.id}" style="display:none;">{$question.id}</div> .. what should i do with JQUERY code to specify id to show it

Comment: @HossamRamadan You still need classes, as it is more convenient to specify this behavior at a class level. Please re-read the answer.  The code you need is there.

Comment: i'm confused sorry :S  but i'm new with Jquery .. i've copied the code in the end of my post above .. could you please check it ?

Comment: @HossamRamadan It looks fine. Is it not working? If so, what is the behavior you see?

Comment: when i click answer there is no window appear